# Need help finding the name of a short story involving Time Travel, gangsters and dinosaurs/prehistoric reptiles

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, dinosaurs

Way back in the late 80's or 90's I read a short story in one of the Science Fiction magazines that were still being published at that time. Unfortunately I cannot recall the name, author or even which magazine it was in. I subscribed to several and purchased others off the news stands when I saw stories that I thought looked interesting. I realize it is a long shot but I thought if I briefly described the plot someone might recognize it.

PLOT: A professor at a small state college in Florida discovers a way to travel to the past. To build his device he is financed by gangsters who, for a fee, intend to send other criminals back in time to escape their current legal problems. A fancy resort is built in the past that provides luxurious comfort, freedom from law enforcement and protection from the local prehistoric animals. Many of the creatures are killed during the construction and afterwards as they continue to try to breach the protective walls. Most, if not all, I believe are aquatic and I think the site of the resort is a breeding ground. I'm not positive about the breeding ground. Anyway, ultimately the animals attack in force and succeed in breaching the perimeter and begin to demolish every building in sight. I think the person telling the story is either a drunk or gambler that was down on his luck but I can't remember why he was there in the first place or why he was even hired by the gangsters. He and the wife of the professor become cozy and they escape the slaughter by traveling back to their own time.

I realize this is not much to go on, especially if the story is an obscure one. Does anyone know if there are any lists of the stories published by the magazines, ie. Fantasy & Science Fiction or Isaac Asimov's Science Fiction? These are two of the ones I subscribed to. ANY help you can provide will be greatly appreciated. Even if no one can provide the name of the story, perhaps you can give me some tips on searching for it.

Comment: You can look at the contents of magazine issues at the Internet Speculative Fiction Database.  Here's a link to the Fantasy and Science Fiction magazine entry.  Good luck! http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?20325